# iOS 6 UI distorted

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, ios7

I have created my app on xCode 5 for iOS 7. When I test my app on iOS 6 I find the entire UI to be distorted. I cant use autolayout since I have to support iOS 5 as well. Is there any other way out?

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more information. Screenshots, code.

Comment: Vote to close as **Demonstrates a minimal understanding** also it's not hard to google and find https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/ a little bit of research goes a long way have a read of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380

Comment: yea well popeye.. quite helpful. Thank you. I tried to find ways to solve it. I changed the view as to 6.1 or earlier then it distorts iOS 7 layout. Couldnt find anything so turned to stack overflow. Thanks a ton mate! Thats how you help people in trouble?

Answer (score 4):

You can use IOS 6/7 Deltas to layout Your UIComponents.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH14-SW1

You can refer above link.